# Dynamic partial name for an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, partial

```
render @some_object
```

will render `Rails.root/app/views/some_objects/_some_object.html.erb`

Now I want to handle which partial will be rendered depends on its `data_type` field. For example:

```
class SomeObject < AR::Base
  # some magick method wich I need to rewrite
  def partial_name
    case data_type
    when "String"
      "string_template"
    when "Text"
      "text_template"
    else
      "blank_template"
    end
  end
end
```

I know there is `model_name`, `i18n_key` and some others, which are returnes model name, but which one is used in my `render @object` case?

**EDIT**

Now I've stopped on the easiest solution that didn't touch models. I removed all this logic into `_some_object.html.erb` partial, so it renders partial I need inside of itself:

```
<div class='claim_template_field'>
  <%= render "/some_objects/#{f.object.data_type.downcase}_template", :f => f %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I've stopped on the easiest solution that didn't touch models. I removed all this logic into _some_object.html.erb partial, so it renders partial I need inside of itself:

```
<div class='claim_template_field'>
  <%= render "/some_objects/#{f.object.data_type.downcase}_template", :f => f %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a limit set of values for the `data_type` field you could create subclasses from SomeObject, one for each data_type.

```
class SomeObject < AR::Base
  inheritance_column :data_type
end
```

Then you could create a default partial for each subclass.

This isn't exactly a "dynamic" solution, but I thought I'd throw it out as a suggestion.

Comment: it is really dynamic, but it will be too complicated with my mongodb data scheme

Answer (score 1):

actionpack/lib/view/action_view/render/partials.rb defines a method for determining the partial path for objects:

```
      def partial_path(object = @object)
        @partial_names[object.class.name] ||= begin
          object = object.to_model if object.respond_to?(:to_model)

          object.class.model_name.partial_path.dup.tap do |partial|
            path = @view.controller_path
            partial.insert(0, "#{File.dirname(path)}/") if partial.include?(?/) && path.include?(?/)
          end
        end
      end
```

You will probably need to define model_name to return a String that has the partial_path method defined.