# A messy view layer, should I depart from MVC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, model-view-controller, refactoring, solid-principles

I'm moving the question here from IRC.

The problem: I have jumped in into a  code base that I want to take on good shape. Don't we always?

In that spirit, after adding some coverage (as in test coverage) I've applied
several known refactorings/improvements to help with this task. Here's what I've
done (actually I've done a lot more, but these are the relevant bits to my question):

1. Added some PORO objects to offload some tasks being performed in models, controllers, even in views.
2. Used *decent_exposure* to get rid of the instance variable hell the view layer was in.
3. Implemented some for-views decorators using *draper* to avoid having so much logic in views.
4. Added presenters for actions spawing multiple models.

Now, I (optimistically) expected all this will pay off. It is better in deed, but after throwing everything but the kitchen sink, I would have expected it to be *lots* better. It's not.

Since I have a view layer that literally is rendering like 10-15 partials on a single action, I'm concerned about my ability to change things in the controller or the view layer. I don't want to go through all this partials whenever I decide the members for an account are called "members" or just "users". I'm caring about this because the model layer is scheduled to suffer more significant change.

What I initially thought (and still stand on) is to have dumb views. I want most part of my view layer to avoid knowing about the models they're rendering at all. I want an intermediary object that will know how to do two things: extracting the data it needs from the model, and rendering the HTML. And before you tell me I'm violating SRP here, the real responsability for this object can be read as "displaying a model to the end user".

In an over-simplification, I would like my views (at least these aforementioned ones) to look like this:

```
= some_object.render
= another_object.render
```

It does sound like the decorator pattern, and it does also sound like the presenter pattern, at least this is what I've though.

Then I started thinking I would be debiating significantly from MVC (at the least the MVC that rails exposes), so I wanted to know whether this would be the best solution (other than the obvious, nearly impossible with this time-constrains, REWRITE), so I'm more confident about making the shot.

So, with that context, my real questions boils down to:

a) Is switching to MVP, MVVM, MV-whatever the right solution for this problem?

b) If it is, can you tell me about the best solution I could use for this some_object.render view style?

c) If not, can tell you tell how to avoid the hard dependency between those partials and views in general, with a model layer that's could be hours away from being significantly rewritten?

d) Hope you don't get here: YAGNI, so fix afterwards? I'm pretty sure I'm gonna need it.

There's another option that crossed my mind and brought to IRC, not really with the spirit of the title but a valid one (although I'd think overkill for the task at hand):

e) Add a service layer, and make my views map to the "logical" models on that service layer, so I'm able to change the physical models independently of the views.

Comment: Decorators could meet your criteria

Comment: I'm not sure whether you followed along the whole question. I'm pretty sure I'd be decorating models, so it doesn't really add up. I need a layer of indirection for my views, whether it is presenter-based, service-based, etc. I was asking about comments on the best solution and hopefully some pointers along the way.

Comment: Did you ever considered using decoratirs to render partials? If so you could achieve what you expect. With a twist of `content_for` you could even nest them

Answer (score 3):

This question is difficult to answer, mainly because your exact problem is vague. Interestingly, I think this is also why you feel you need help to move forward.

**To summarize:**

You've already refactored to:

- dumb views
- clean views
- tested views

Still, your main complaint:

> I have a view layer that literally is rendering like 10-15
>   partials on a single action, I'm concerned about my ability to change
>   things in the controller or the view layer. I don't want to go through
>   all this partials

**What I would do:**

I'd solve the "I have too many view files" by merging related views together.

I'd solve the "I can't find my view code" by organizing my views to better fit how the code is actually changing.

**Notes:**

It sounds like you're facing 2 anti-patterns:

- solution sprawl (over decomposition)
- over use of patterns

If 10-15 partials seems excessive, maybe it is! Is each partial re-used in the code base? Can they be grouped better (so I can render 1 instead of 3)? Can I send one partial some data to tweak its rendering rather than create 2 partials?

It sounds like you may have gone too far in your 'division of responsibility' and the sheer volume of views is getting in your way. Maybe Re-composition is the path forward?

Looking to MVP, MVVM, etc is the wrong direction. Getting hung up on patterns might be hurting you a bit. For instance,

```
# how is this:
= some_object.render

# different from this?
= render "some_object"
```

A view can certainty be responsible for "displaying a model to the end user"

I feel your pain, sometimes code volume alone is a problem. Organization and grouping, while low tech, can be the best way to tackle it though.

Comment: on dumb views: I don't *have* them, I *want* them.
I think merging related views isn't an option, just to mention line count (even after cleaned)

Comment: My refactorings are not really "getting in my way". The model layer
(I know I under-emphasized this) is going to be changed a lot, that's my concern. I want a shield from that, and no, I'm not a java developer ;) I just happen to think I'd need it.
Overuse of patterns? The "throwing everything but the kitchen sink" line was a bad joke. Views were performing complex conditional and display, models were enqueing background workers (many of them), controllers were pulling data from multiple models... So, you'd tell me.

Comment: some_object.render is different from render some_object because the former would know how to extract
the model data, know how to render itself, and it'll be self-contained, I won't potentially need
to hook into the rendering stack for doing this, but instead return a string buffer from that object call.
Those objects some times yes, will render a partial, sometimes I might need them to render several of them, I need to have the freedom of doing the rendering my way

Comment: Still the best answer I can give without more details. If you're up to it, make another question with a specific view(s)/model(s) and the specific change you want to shield yourself from. I can take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Not a general answer to your question, but for this *particular* problem you mention:

> I don't want to go through all this partials whenever I decide the members for an account are called "members" or just "users".

Use Rails i18n. It's not just for actual i18n, it's also a great way to dry out user-displayable terms and other language, like this.

That might be a clue to the general answer to your question: There might not *be* just one answer, there might be different answers to improving the maintainability and comprehensibility of different aspects of your code.

This stuff is hard, probably don't trust anyone that says that there's a magic bullet and if you just do it the way they say everything will be great -- esp if they're saying it without knowing any more details then the general/generic desription of your project/problem you've given us.

But I don't think there's anything wrong with a presenter/decorator approach if it seems to make things better. Just remember to keep it simple; if you can get away with pure no-magic ruby decorator/presenter, I think that's better than using some fancy mysteriously-implemented rails engine for it. Always remember the goal is to make things as simple as possible (and no simpler), and you're on the right path. (Yes, sometimes I realize after the fact that I've terribly overcomplicated things in an effort to keep them simple. oops).

### For another part of what I *think* your question is,

I have sometimes used decorators on my models to provide methods that return partial names to be used to render them. I'm not sure I've been entirely happy with the solution when I've done that, but, hey, it's not -that- different than Rails' own magic way of guessing a partial name for a model (which there's probably -some- way to customize or parameterize, but nobody can ever remember/find it). And I think it's better than `some_object.render`.  Instead, more like `render :partial => some_object.render_partial_name, :object => some_object`.

Or you could provide that intermediate object you mention, which is basically a presenter-type thing, actually pretty similar to above although with a different object graph:

```
PresentWidget.new( some_object ).render
```

But then you've got to use some magic to make a seperate object like that able to call ActionView render appropriately. Some of the magic rails presenter engines help you do that. But I always get turned off by too much magic.

Or you could look at Cells.  I often think I want Cells for problems like this, although personally when I start trying to use it, I always end up at "too much magic, too much fighting with rails" and abandon it again.

and a similar stack overflow question, also without any particularly stunning solutions, but maybe it'll give you ideas: [Dynamic partial name for an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733549/dynamic-partial-name-for-an-object)

Of all the options though, I would *not* give the models themselves a `#render` method, personally.  hooking a freestanding presenter into ActionView so it can call `render` is one thing, hooking a model into it like that seems even worse.

### And lastly, you sure a rewrite isn't better than a rewrite?

After you spend all this time thinking through and implementing this kind of architecture -- you may find it would have been quicker to have rewritten the thing in the first place, the thing you keep saying you have no time for. If it's obvious to you how to rewrite it to be cleaner, but not obvious how to add this weird meta rigamarole on top to be cleaner... why not just do what's obvious?  Adding this stuff on top will be rewriting/refactoring too, naturally.